# Replace in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string something like this:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
```

And would like to return this part:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/
```

How can I do this using pure javascript?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will match and remove the last part of a string after the slash.

```js
url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"
base = url.replace(/[^/]*$/, "")
document.write(base)
```

Help from: http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: I don't think he wanted to remove the trailing slash

Answer (score 0):

For slicing off last part:

```js
var test = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask';
var last = test.lastIndexOf('/');
var result = test.substr(0, last+1);

document.write(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with the .replace() method on String objects. 
For example:

```
//Regex way
var x = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask";
x = x.replace(/ask/, "");

//String way
x = x.replace('ask', "");

//x is now equal to the string "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/"
```

The replace method takes two parameters. The first is what to replace, which can either be a string or regex, literal or variable, and the second parameter is what to replace it with.